# Does the c++ apps build for android run on top of JVM of on the Kernal

Tags: android, c++

In android does the application built with c++ (and packages in apps Like [Termux](https://termux.com/)) run on top of the Dalvik JVM or directly communicate with the Linux Kernal

Comment: What do you want to ask? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained partly in the [Concepts](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts) section of the Android NDK documentation.

In brief: every Android user application needs to run the Android event loop in some capacity to receive events, participate in the application lifecycle, and display stuff on the screen.

What people call "native" c++ applications are actually running a "hollow" Java Android application/activity on top of ART (the Android "Java" runtime). The native part is expected to do everything that you get for free from normal Java-based activities: pump events and update the screen regularly.

Now, to answer your final question: for *some* aspects they can use the Android kernel directly. However, this is a very limited set of operations and more interesting operations either require some of the native APIs (which use an RPC mechanism called Binder to talk to system services) or use JNI to talk to a Java implementation (that in turn probably still uses Binder).